# C code performance comparison, why is one of them much faster

Tags: c, performance, optimization

Recently I started solving problems from an online judge: http://coj.uci.cu/

And I solved one problem about calculating the least power of two of a number

(Full description: http://coj.uci.cu/24h/problem.xhtml?pid=1158)

SAMPLE INPUT

```
2    // This means we want to perform the algorithm twice for the next input
4
192
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
4
64
```

After you solve you can compare your answer with the others so this are two different codes that solve the same problem (the basic idea is to keep dividing by two until the modulus is different from zero, then we find the minimum power and make 2*minimum to find the answer)

MY SOLUTION

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a,result;
    int i = 0;
    int leastPow = 1;
    scanf("%d",&a);             // Read the number of conversions
    for(i = 0; i < a; i++){
        scanf("%d",&result);    // Read the number to calculate the least pow
        while(result!=0){       // While there is still divisions to make...       
            if(result%2!=0)    
                break;          // hence we break the loop, we are done...
            result = result/2;  // Otherwise we can keep on dividing
            leastPow *= 2;
        }
        printf("%d\n",leastPow);// Print the result
        leastPow = 1;          // Re initialize for next number
    }
    return 0;
}
```

One of the top solutions (by nilre)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long pot,n;
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%Ld",&n);
        pot = 1;
        while(n)
            if(n%2 == 0)
            {
                pot *= 2;
                n /= 2;
            }else break;
        printf("%Ld\n",pot);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For me the codes look very similar but the online judge gives the following performance results

MY SOLUTION

```
Time: 37 ms
Mem:  1 MB
Size: 1 KB
```

OTHER SOLUTION

```
Time: 0 ms
Mem:  270 bytes
Size: 348 bytes
```

I am very curious about what makes such a great difference in performance

Comment: Why don't you look at the assembly for each and compare?  `gcc -O3 -S program.c`

Comment: I didn't know that was possible, I am kind of a beginner but thanks for the advise I will look into it as well

Comment: The `%Ld` format used is not valid according to the standard (in either [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) or [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), so the alternative answer is invoking platform-specific behaviour.  (With both functions, the `L` modifier is for use with the floating-point conversions to indicate `long double`.)  I'm left wondering if the zero time is because the code invokes undefined behaviour and the program is left empty, leading to the 0 millisecond execution time.

Comment: A difference between the two is that you use `int` whereas the other uses `long long int`. If the input file contains numbers that are bigger than `INT_MAX` then your code causes undefined behaviour . Do you know whether the input file does indeed contain such numbers?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in that case the program would not generate the expected output  (so in theory the judge would reject it)

Comment: The specification includes _The input contains several test cases and begins with a number T (T <= 10^3) denoting how many test cases there are. T lines follow, each one with a single positive integer in the range [1, 2^63-1]._  There are few systems where plain `int` is a 64-bit quantity.

Comment: @M.M: agreed, but it is surprising that it can read and calculate and report up to 1000 minimal powers of 2 so quickly that it takes less than 1 ms.

Comment: @M.M You are right the online judge specifies a range of [1, 2^63 - 1] for the input which will probably lead to a wrong answer from my code, although the solution was accepted, but is there a relationship with performance there?

Comment: @OmarMuñoz yes, when your program triggers undefined behaviour then anything can happen.  There's no point trying to reason about it really. Fix your code to use `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long` , and the correct format specifier (`"%" SCNu64` or `"%llu"` respectively) and see if the performance difference remains

Comment: @M.M: `LLONG_MAX` has to be at least 2^63-1, so I don't see why there's a problem using `long long` types.  If you meant `LONG_MAX`, then I'd agree that it could be as small as 2^31-1 — but it could also be 2^63-1.  It depends on the hardware and software used by the online judge.

Comment: Oh, right. I mentally read that as 2^64-1 for some reason.